# How to handle html5 canvas object with jCrop plugin?

Tags: html, object, image-processing, canvas, jcrop

I'm looking for a long time solution and I can not find anywhere. If I have for exemple this html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<table>
<img src="picture.jpg" id="picture" style="display:none"/>
<tr>
<td>
<canvas id="rotate"></canvas>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
    <strong>Rotate Image: </strong>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="resetImage">Reset Image</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="rotate90">90&deg;</a>
</p>
</html>
```

and I want rotate the image with some javascript rotate function and after that I need crop them with jCrop plugin. Is there a way to handle canvas object with jCrop plugin. I tryied to do this like that, but not working:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#rotate').Jcrop({
    bgColor: 'black',
bgOpacity: .8,
setSelect: [ 10, 10, 200, 300 ],
    aspectRatio: 2 / 3
    });
});
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it after long time with imgareaSelect, pixastic, and jQuery libraries. The problem now is that the script is working a bit slowly, so I have to do some optimization. You can see working script [here](http://agd-brita.pl/mobile2/canvas.html).

We can rotate and flip the remote picture in any direction and do some more image processing with our local pictures.